# I'm unable to run the script through npm run command. My script name is "start". whenever i run this script through this command i got error

Tags: node.js

Actually I'm trying to deploy my app to Heroku(it is not about a problem with Heroku). Previously I was running the script on my local machine by just running app.js (script name). but now I have to modify my packege.json by adding "start":"node src/app.js" script. But whenever I run the command (npm run start) it generates the error.

I have tried "start":"node app.js". I have checked the location of the script correctly it is in the src folder but still is not working.

```
{
      "name": "src",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "app.js",
      "scripts": {
          "start": "node src/app.js"    // here I declare the start
  },
```

This script has to start the server

Comment: Can you add the error information to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to run `npm start`.